# addClause always returns empty collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

***Edit2: The problem is solved now thanks to @tabacitu. Thanks to everyone who tried to help! Please refer to this github thread for further information while I update the question: https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/2049***

***Edit: I have tried this on a completely fresh backpack installation using only the `User` model. Same problem.***

Added the following route at the and of `routes/backpack/custom.php`:

`Route::get('test/{id}', 'UserCrudController@index');`

This is my URL: `https://example.com/admin/test/30`

Then added the following code to my `UserCrudController.php`:

```
$id = \Route::current()->parameter('id');
```

Now again, this doesn't work:

`$this->crud->addClause('where','id', "=", $id); //produces empty result, but $id contains 30`

But this does work:

`$this->crud->addClause('where','id', "=", 30); //here I get my user with id 30.`

---

I have an **`Article`** model and am using `$this->crud->addClause('where','user_id',backpack_user()->id);` to limit the articles shown to those belonging to the currently logged in user.

I now want to further filter my articles by **only showing articles that have a certain `page_id`** - in fact, I can do this without any hassle:

`$this->crud->addClause('where','page_id', "=", "154");`

Now only articles that have a `page_id` of 154 are shown.

Obviously I want a dynamic variable for page_id, so my url looks like this

`http://example.com/admin/articles/154`

and I extract the last parameter like this:

```
$segments = request()->segments();
$page_id = $segments[count($segments)-1]; //get last segment, contains "154"
```

Now my problem is that for some obscure reason, whenever I try to use

`$this->crud->addClause('where','page_id', "=", $page_id);`

The collection is empty, even tho dd()'ing `$page_id` shows it *is* set and contains "154". I have even tried to cast $page_id to int like this and in fact it becomes an int but still the same problem (empty collection):

`$page_id = (int)$segments[count($segments)-1]; //shows 154`

---

Edit: Here are the outputs of `dd($this->crud->query->toSql());`:

```
//limit access to user owned models
$this->crud->addClause('where','user_id',backpack_user()->id);    
//produces "select * from `articles` where `user_id` = ?"
dd($this->crud->query->toSql());

//limit entries to those with samge page_id as in URL
$page_id = \Route::current()->parameter('page_id');
$this->crud->addClause('where','page_id',$page_id);       
//produces "select * from `articles` where `user_id` = ? and `page_id` = ?"
dd($this->crud->query->toSql());
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you print  the query log and see whats the last query after you added $page_id

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question accordingly. Query logs look ok at least I can't find any anomaly there.

Comment: What about `dd($this->crud->query->getBindings());` ?

Comment: In the original part you said you use `request->segments` to get the page id, but in the edit part, it becomes `Route->parameter`. So if you still type `/154` in the address bar then..

Comment: `dd($this->crud->query->getBindings());` shows the intended result (array containing 2 elements: `0 => my_user_id` and 1 => `my_page_id`. Sry for using `request->segments` first then `Route->parameter` but it shouldn't make a difference as the resulting page_id is always the same.

Comment: I feel like the problem is not where we expect to be. Can you confirm that when you do `154`, or `$page_id = 154` or `$page_id = ...->parameter('page_id')` **with any other change and the same user, on the same environment** only `154` or `$page_id = 154`  will work? Keeping in mind that `->parameter('page_id')` returns `"154"`

Comment: Are you telling that if you replaced just this `$this->crud->addClause('where','page_id', "=", $page_id);` with this `$this->crud->addClause('where','page_id', "=", "154");` **without changing any other thing**, you get the expected result ??

Comment: I meant **without any**

Comment: @cbaconnier Thanks for your reply. I also feel like the problem is somewhere else. I can confirm that as soon as I set `$page_id = 154` manually, it works! Yet if I `dd` the content of $page_id when NOT set manually, it shows `154`!

Comment: @Adrenaxus Since you direct set $page_id = 154 and it work. So your dd($page_id) displayed as **154**, but it not actual 154 number. How about the way you define your route ? Your route define could add some special character (blank character) so it make your query do not work. Further more, even depend on your keyboard encode that make your URL display **154**, but no really 154 number.

Comment: Can you try `DB::enableQueryLog(); //your query               \Log::debug(DB::getQueryLog());  DB::disableQueryLog();` and let us know the query you are generating?

Comment: @Adrenaxus What versions (php, laravel, backpack) are you running?

Comment: @Adrenaxus Finally, maybe a silly question, but are you completely sure you are running all these tests against the same database - it looks like there are no records in DB matching your criteria, code seems fine (int,string - both should be automatically converted to int and just work)

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu listening to the query log always produces an empty array, it doesn't produce anything other than an empty array anywhere in my application.

Comment: @Bart I have PhP v7.2.22, Laravel 5.8 and backpack 3.5. Also I am sure that all the tests are running against the same DB. In fact, as I said, as soon as I manually set the variable it works so it must be the right DB...

Comment: I don't know if this works on laravel backpack. But can't you get the id like this in your controller? `public function index($id)` ?

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Forgetting about a cache, confusing your variables, who knows. Questions from new users claiming that replacing a variable with a scalar fixes all their problems are quite common, and always misguided. There is nothing more basic in a programming language than simple variable assignment, and I can assure you it is not broken.

Comment: BTW I attempted to install this software onto a fresh Laravel 5.8 project, but its installer `php artisan backpack:base:install` got hung up in Composer hell.

Answer (score 2):

Time to swoop in for the bounty! :-) Copy of my answer in [this thread](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/2049).

Your problem is most likely with the AJAX datatables URL. It doesn't get the parameter, so it doesn't apply it.

Basically:

- the `/town_id/x` route points to `Controller::index()`
- `CrudController::index()` just loads the view;
- the view tells DataTables to load the information from the `url($crud->route.'/search').'?'.Request::getQueryString()` route; which will NOT include your town_id parameter; because it uses `$crud->route()`, which is specified in your `setup()`; it does NOT include `/town_id/x`;

#### SOLUTION A

One way to get around this:

- instead of having a route for it, use a GET parameter: `example.com/admin/users/?town_id=20`
- you'll be able to get that parameter and apply things to `search()` from your `setup()` method:

```php
        if (\Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionMethod() == 'search' && \Request::has('town_id')) {
            $this->crud->addClause('where', 'select', \Request::get('town_id'));
        }
```

#### SOLUTION B

Overwrite the `datatables_logic.blade.php` file that Backpack provides, and replace `$crud->route` with `Route::getCurrentRoute()` or something of that nature - use Laravel's way of getting the current URL, instead of `$this->crud`. This will make your AJAX calls to the current URL (not the URL you defined for the CRUD with `$this->crud->setRoute()`).

---

I would recommend option 1, to be honest.

Comment: Not quite. The variable DID contain the right value in index(). It’s just that the search happens in a different method, search(), and by the time it reaches that method the parameter gets stripped.

Answer (score 1):

I am install demo of [backpack](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/demo) and tried it. I am test it in `MonsterCrudController` and everything was right.

The question mark `(?)` in `dd($this->crud->query->toSql());`doesn't matter at all.

[image]

But my suggestion:

Try this one first

```
$this->crud->addClause('where','id', "=", (int)$id);
```

If it doesn't work for you, be sure to trace your `$id` variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the problem still persists. If I use `$this->crud->addClause('where','page_id', "=", "'7'");` still doesnt work, `$this->crud->addClause('where','page_id', "=", "7");` works, also `$this->crud->addClause('where','page_id', "=", strval(7));` works as well.

Comment: Please set manually $page_id  and test again. `$page_id =  155`. @Adrenaxus

Comment: I wrote many times in comments and in my original post that if I set `$page_id` manually it always works.

Comment: Are you test this `$page_id=154; $this->crud->addClause('where','page_id', "=", $page_id);` @Adrenaxus

Comment: Yes, I tried exactly that and can confirm that it works. I'm beginning to think that for some reason `$this->crud->addClause(` cannot accept a variable... or you need to define a helper function like `backpack_user` in `src/helpers.php` that returns the variable... or need to use `use($variable)` in some closure or something....

Comment: Could you please also check the `$this->crud->addClause('where','page_id', "=", 0+$page_id);`

Comment: Let's be ugly as hell : `$this->crud->addClause('where', 'page_id', '=', &$page_id);`

Comment: `$this->crud->addClause('where','page_id', "=", 0+$page_id);` doesnt work, and `$this->crud->addClause('where', 'page_id', '=', &$page_id);` produces "unexpected '&'" error.

Comment: Surely your `$page_id variable` is having a problem. @Adrenaxus

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your code? @Adrenaxus

Comment: Sure, I can share whatever is needed. Please look at my edit, I tried everything with a *fresh* backpack installation with only 3 lines of code added - should be easier to debug that.

Comment: @Adrenaxus What you mean saying `0+$page_id` doesnt work? Is the result the same as without `0+`?

Comment: I am now creating a project with the same specifications and then testing. @Adrenaxus

Comment: @MahdiBashirpour `query->toSql()` doesn't show actual value bindings. Database driver (mysqlnd) is responsible for query preparation and value binding.
Was `addClause('where', 'page_id', "=", $page_id)` succesfull in your environment?

Comment: That is succesfull run in my environment. @Constantine